# How to download previous version of Werkzeug

Tags: python, werkzeug

How do I download previous version of Werkzeug from a trusted site?

Here is what I have tried:

1) I went to this link:
http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/installation/#installing-a-released-version
and clicked on the "Download Page" link.

It took me to the 0.10.4 download page.

2) I googled "Werkzeug download 0.9" and only got references to 0.10.  There was a download link to a versioneye.com site that I don't know if I can trust.

I need to download the previous version because 0.10.x dropped support for support for OpenSSL.

[edit] I have to download rather than install from pip because I don't have access to pip on the old machine I am installing on.  It is old, hence the complications.

[edit] I had to use the older version because 0.10.x dropped support for the OpenSSL package in favor of ssl built into Python 2.7.9.  I was stuck on Python 2.7.5 so I wanted to continue to use OpenSSL package.  I think they made the right decision to drop support as the majority of people can upgrade to 2.7.9.

Comment: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/releases

Comment: Why did you have to downgrade Werkzeug?

Answer (score 7):

You can install an old package with pip:

```
  pip install Werkzeug==0.9.6
```

Comment: I voted this up because it is a good answer for those who can install from pip.  I edited my question to clarify that I cannot install from pip.

Answer (score 0):

Building on f43d65's comment, I have refined it to these steps which include making sure it is coming from a reliable source:

1. goto the official website: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/
2. click link to official github account: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug
3. click on releases tab: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/releases

Note: the instructions make sure that the download is coming from the official source.

Answer (score 0):

go in pycharm settings and then in interprator click on + there in packages and then search for werkzeug there, after click on versions and choose old version. it did work for me.